# Why is the word for afternoon (צהריים) plural?

Tags: words, hebrew

Why is the word for afternoon (צהריים) plural but morning (בוקר) and evening (ערב) are singular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pasuk in [Shemos 12:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.12.6?lang=bi&aliyot=0) writes:

> וְהָיָ֤ה לָכֶם֙ לְמִשְׁמֶ֔רֶת עַ֣ד אַרְבָּעָ֥ה עָשָׂ֛ר י֖וֹם לַחֹ֣דֶשׁ הַזֶּ֑ה וְשָׁחֲט֣וּ אֹת֗וֹ כֹּ֛ל קְהַ֥ל עֲדַֽת־יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל **בֵּ֥ין הָעַרְבָּֽיִם**
>
> You shall keep watch over it until the fourteenth day of this month; and all the assembled congregation of the Israelites shall slaughter it **at twilight**.

[Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.12.6.1?vhe=On_Your_Way_New&lang=bi) there writes as follows:

> ואחר הבקר יקרא העת צהרים, כמו שנאמר מהבקר ועד הצהרים (מלכים א י״ח:כ״ו), והן שתי השעות החמישית והשישית, והוא מלשון צוהר תעשה לתיבה (בראשית ו טז), כענין זוהר. **ויזכיר בהן לשון רבים, בעבור שהן שתים. והנה הם שני צהרים, או מפני שיצהירו כל הצדדין**, כי בבקר האור במזרח, ובערב הוא במערב, ובאמצע היום בגובה הרקיע מאיר לכל הצדדין
>
> ...After morning, the time is called tzohorayim (noonday), just as it is said, from morning until ‘tzohorayim’ (noon) [[I Kings 18:26]](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.18.26?lang=bi). It consists of two hours: the fifth and the sixth hours of the day. The word tzohorayim is of the root ‘tzohar’ (A light) shalt thou make to the ark, and implies brightness. **It is written in the plural [tzohorayim] because it is the two [brightest parts of the day] which, so to speak, make two tzohorayim. It may be that it is written in the plural because light is then disseminated on all sides.** In the morning the light is centered in the east, and towards evening it is in the west, but in the middle of the day when it is high in the sky, it gives light on all sides.